# fontspec and xeCJK conflict: tie (\t{}) over Latin character displaced one position

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, cjk, xecjk

I want to create a tie over `ng` by typing: `\t{ng}`:

[image: Working tie]

The following minimal example causes the tie over *ng* to be displaced one position to the right, so that it appears over the *g* and empty space. The problem persists regardless of font. It works fine if I don't load either `xeCJK` or `fontspec`, but not if I load both.

I'm compiling with `xelatex` on Mac OS Mavericks.

```
\documentclass[utf8,12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}
\begin{document}
\t{ng}
\end{document}
```

[image: Displaced tie]

Comment: It seems a bug of `xunicode-addon`. A quick fix is to use `\t ng` instead of `\t{ng}`. We will check the code later.

Comment: I use it inside words and over several combinations of letters, so there is not really a quick fix in my case. I'll sit tight and wait for an update of the package. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest revision of `xunicode-addon` try to fix this bug (avaliable in [`ctex-kit`](http://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/issues/detail?id=138) or [`Google Driver`](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByoqtDyaHv0bWEFMNVJaZkdLaDA) currently). Please have a try.

**Update:** The new version is available in TeX Live 2013.

Comment: I'm not very good at changing things in my LaTeX installation manually, I'll wait until it's available for update through TeX Live. 多謝!

Comment: @Mårten: You can download the files in Google Driver and decompress the files to your working directory. That's it.

Comment: I added the .sty and the .def files in `texmf` and loaded `\usepackage{xunicode-addon}`. It did not solve the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Scratch that; it now works, miraculously. Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually, I have to withdraw that. I still find many instances where it is not working although I load the package.

Comment: @Mårten: Please show your "many instances" to let me know how to fix it.

Comment: Actually, it is every word. It might be that I haven't installed the patch correctly. I have put it in my TeX tree and I load \usepackage{xunicode-addon}, perhaps I'm doing it wrong? I only know how to use TeX on a very basic level.

Comment: Ok, it is working again now. I really cannot tell you why, but I apologize for the confusion and thank you for your help.

Comment: @Mårten: Please feel free. FYI, the new version is available in TeX Live, you can get it via tlmgr. I am very glad to hear any feedback about `xeCJK`.

Comment: Actually, that might have been why it worked! I just updated all packages yesterday before noticing that it had started working